# Build and Run an old Android Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am given the zipped project source code of an Android project integrated to AWS services. I need to understand and be able to add some new functionalities to the app but I cannot successfully run the project in android studio. I am using Android Studio 4.1.3.

I am new to Android and AWS and I am just learning these technologies.

How and where should I start studying the code?

Also if you could help me solve the issue I am encountering in Android Studio.
I already tried killing all gradle daemons and killing all java processes but I still encounter the same issue.

**Android Studio Issue**

*Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/collections/DirectoryFileTreeFactory;)V'
org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/collections/DirectoryFileTreeFactory;)V*

*Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)*

*Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.*

*Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.*

*In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.*

**below is the build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.9.+'
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()  }}
task clean(type: Delete) {delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

**below is the build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dostcandle.ecrf"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}}
dependencies {
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
def room_version = "2.2.1"
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.+'
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
implementation 'ph.ingenuity.tableview:tableview:0.1.0-alpha'

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.8.+'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.15.+'

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.15.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.15.+'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'}
```

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048340/android-gradle-unable-to-find-method-org-grade-api-internal-file-defaultsourced, This might be help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of the AppSync SDK that is not compatible with Android Gradle Plugin 4.x / Gradle 6+. Right now, I see that you're using AGP 4.x.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/issues/270) for more details.

You have two options:

1. Use older versions of Gradle & Android Gradle Plugin. Specifically, 3.6.3 of the plugin, and 5.6.4 of Gradle.
2. Update your AppSync dependencies to *at least* 3.1+. See [the setup notes in the project's README](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/blob/main/README.md#setup) for more details.

Source: I authored the fix for this issue in the AppSync SDK.

Comment: Thank you Jameson, I have updated AWS AppSync SDK setup. The application is building now but it crashes when opened.
I think the issue is with the AWS Amplify setup. I saw a post containing a depricated AWS Amplify setup and that was the one followed in the app. Can you point me in the right direction on how can I update the AWS Amplify setup to the latest one?

Comment: @akgm You aren't actually using Amplify -- you're using the AWS Mobile SDK for Android.The latest version of the Android SDK is 2.23.0. (See https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.23.0 .) To update, find all dependencies like com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk*. Change every 2.15.+ to 2.23.0. Feel free to upvote/accept this solution if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**apply these:**

```
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

**instead of these:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

**if still it does not work then simple add these:**

```
android {
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Tried this but I am getting this error instead.


_Build file '/home/liyah/AndroidStudioProjects/ecrf/app/build.gradle' line: 11_

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method id() for arguments [com.android.application] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

Create new project most of the code should be obsolete. If you want to run existing code change jcenter() to mavenCentral() also check aws documentationhttps://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // Add this line into `dependencies` in `buildscript`
        classpath 'com.amplifyframework:amplify-tools-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.amplifyframework.amplifytools'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dostcandle.ecrf"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.17.3'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:1.17.3'

    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    implementation 'ph.ingenuity.tableview:tableview:0.1.0-alpha'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.8.+'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.22.6'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.22.6'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.22.6'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```